# UIImagePickerController dismissModalViewController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to invoke UIImagePickerController to select a movie on iPhone 3GS and when the movie is selected, i just dismiss it and present MyViewController modally with a configured delay of 1.0 seconds. What I notice is 10% of the times, presentModalViewController on MyViewController does nothing whereas it works 90% of the times. I want to understand why is this behavior and what is the remedy. Here is the sample code:

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
  {

  NSURL *videoURL = nil;

  NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

  ```
  if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"])
  ```

  {

  ```
    videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
  ```

  }

  picker.delegate = nil;

  [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  [self performSelector:@selector(launchMyViewController:) withObject:nil
       afterDelay:1.0];

}

-(void) launchMyViewController:(id) obj
{

```
MyViewController *myCtrl = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] controller:self];

[self presentModalViewController:myCtrl animated:YES];
[myCtrl release];
NSLog(NSStringFromClass([self.modalViewController class]));
[path release];
```

}

I have put NSLog statement to print the self.modalViewController class name and what I notice is that 10% of the times when myCtrl is not fired modally, the self.modalViewController.class is UIImagePickerController. Otherwise, the self.modalViewController.class is MyViewController. I want to know why is the behavior so unpredictable and what is the workaround or other way to achieve the same thing I intend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that using the `performSelector:afterDelay:` call is the problem.  Try calling your launch method immediately, instead of through the delay.